# How to make a view controller scrollable?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiscrollview, scrollview

I have a view controller on which i parse data from a server and show on screen an article. Now the article can have any size from 10 characters to 10000. So what i need is to make the whole view controller scrollable to the user so he can scroll trough the whole article. How can i do that? Can it be done only through the IB? On my view controller i have images and labels to show the articles data.

Or maybe its easier to make only the label that i keep the main articles text scrollable and not the whole controller?

Comment: I would use a `UIScrollView`. (You have to be more specific.)

Comment: I think if you add a UITextView it automatically enables scrolling when there's more text than actually fitting on the screen. I'd consider using UIWebViews for text formatting issues.

Comment: I have on screen an image a title and subtitle on labels (which size is predefined) and under that a label that keep the articles body. This body can be from 100characters which fit the screen or 10000 which doesnt. So i want to be able to scroll through that label.

Answer (score 2):

You must extend UIScrollView by your own class or can alloc/init it.

```
scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size. height)];
scrollView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[scrollView addSubview:otherView];

scrollView.contentSize = scrollView.frame.size;

[self.view addSubview:scrollView];
```

after that you must add views to the scrollView and set properly `contentSize`

Comment: Why this: `scrollView.contentSize = scrollView.frame.size;`?

Comment: Because second view is added on if-else principle after adding second view i've change the contentSize again. But your question is good enough to change it, Thank you.

Comment: Fetch the image and text which you want to display on screen. Create a imageview and attach the image and create a textview and set the text which you want to display. Add these newly created imageview and textview as a subview to a new view(Create new view if you have not done is previously) and then add the new view as a subview of scrollview. By doing this, you can scroll the article. You need to set the contentSize of scrollview if you need to scroll.